# Como hacer que el area de texto y el scroll se adapten al tamaño de la ventana en java?

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo programación y quiero hacer un bloc de notas simple. Use un JTextArea y un JScrollBar que funcionan bien en pantalla completa pero quiero que cuando este en modo ventana  estos se adapten al tamaño de la ventana. Este es el codigo que hize:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Ventana extends JFrame{
    JButton btn = new JButton();
    Button b = new Button();
    
    public Ventana() {
        componentes();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 400); //tamaño de la ventana
        setLayout(null);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); // abre en pantalla completa
    }
    
    public void componentes() {
        Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Insets insets = getInsets();
        int alturaBarraTar = screenSize.height - insets.top - insets.bottom;

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setLineWrap(true); //establece el salto al llegar al borde
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true); //establece si el salto se hara por espacios en blanco o por caracteres
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
        
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scroll.setBounds(0, 0, screenSize.width, alturaBarraTar-60);
        add(scroll);
            
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo mas sencillo es utilizar un *layout*, estos se encargan de organizar y redimensionar los componentes de acuerdo al tamaño del contenedor.

[BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) es uno de ellos y se adapta muy bien para solucionar éste problema.

```
public Ventana() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(600, 400); //tamaño de la ventana
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); // abre en pantalla completa
    componentes();
    setVisible(true);
}

public void componentes() {
    Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    Insets insets = getInsets();
    int alturaBarraTar = screenSize.height - insets.top - insets.bottom;

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setLineWrap(true); //establece el salto al llegar al borde
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true); //establece si el salto se hara por espacios en blanco o por caracteres
    textArea.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
    
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Notese que primero, en este programa en concreto, debe establecerse el *layout* y luego sí agregar cada componente al contenedor, por tanto el metodo `componentes` es invocado despues de especificar `setLayout(new BorderLayout())`.

Por ultimo se agrega el *scroller* de la forma `add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER)` para ubicar tanto el `JTextArea` y el `JScrollPane` justo en el centro de la ventana en donde se van a ajustar automaticamente a cualquier tamaño.